# div having fixed height and fixed position make inner content scroll

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a navigation panel `<div>` which has `heigh:200px` and `position:fixed`. This div should display a vertical scroll bar when it's content is higher than 200px but I don't know how to make that happen.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ernestbofill/j3c6j535/)

I know the fiddle doesn't make much sense but I have a more complex scenario where I need this behaviour.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>
            title1
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title2
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title3
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title4
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title5
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title6
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title7
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try    `overflow-y:scroll`  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3c6j535/1/).[This](http://jsfiddle.net/j3c6j535/2/)  has a `container` just to show that the position will be maintained

```css
.fixed {
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>
            title1
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title2
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title3
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title4
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title5
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title6
        </h1>
        <h1>
            title7
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```